# How to add combobox value out of databank MSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

So I want to add `ComboBox` items with a value out of a databank.
My code now is like this:

```
//Make connection
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(StrConnectionstring);

        //SQL
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Classname, ClassID FROM tblClasses", conn);

        //Open connection
        conn.Open();
        MySqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();



        while (DR.Read())
        {
            CmbClass.DisplayMember = "Text";
            CmbClass.ValueMember = "Value";
            CmbClass.Items.Add( new { Text = Convert.ToString(DR["Classname"]), Value = Convert.ToInt16(DR["ClassID"]) });
        }
```

The Classnames are properly given but when i use the `cmbClass.SelectedValue` it doesn't give any value.

Comment: Where does `DR["Classname"]` come from? Not your query.

Comment: Use a `DataTable.DefaultView` as the `ComboBox.DataSource`. Or use a `BindingSource` (where the `BindingSource.DataSource` is a DataTable or a `List<class>`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some value selected in your combo box.

Also, if you want to use `SelectedValue` you have to use binding first, setting `DataSource` of `ComboBox`. If you don't want to do this, then you could use something as `SelectedItem`.

Also, you are setting `DisplayMemeber` and `ValueMemeber` in a loop, which is unnecessary.
Do it outside the loop.